# Why non of the statement get executed after updating Bootstrap's typeahead data-source?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

By using `autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = JSON.parse(srcArray);` ,
I have done updating typeahead's data-source successfully.

But none of code statements are executing after
`autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = JSON.parse(srcArray);`
Why ?

```
For Example:  
//Last Alert box does not execute here.

alert("Executed");
autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = JSON.parse(srcArray);
alert("Not Executed");
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console? What does `srcArray` exactly contain?

Comment: @RoToRa- For Example:  
`srcArray = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Any"];`  
and there is no error.

Comment: So `srcArray` is already an array? `JSON.parse` converts a JSON **string** into an object/array. There is no need to use it, if you  don't have a string.

Comment: srcArray is basicaly a string....

Comment: Is it? That's not what you wrote in your first comment. And what do you mean with "basically"?